# Should I place logic about authentication on the model?

Tags: laravel

I'm developing an application which involves authentication and files acl.

Now I want to write a method on the file model called "userCanAccess" which check if the given user/ the user role is in the file acl.
The code will be something along those lines:

```
public function userCanAccess($user = null) {
    $user = is_null($user) ? auth()->user() : $user;
    
    if($this->acl->users->contains($user) 
    || $this->acl->roles->contains($user->role)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false
}
```

Is it right to place this kind of logic on the model?

Comment: This belongs in a policy. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization#creating-policies

Comment: @ceejayoz Thanks, didn't know about policies! Could you please write it in an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel has a neat built-in bit of functionality called [Policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization#creating-policies).

You'd create a `FilePolicy` that applies to the File model:

```
 php artisan make:policy FilePolicy --model=File
```

and in the resulting `app/Policies/FilePolicy.php`, you'll see some ready-to-edit existing policies, one of which is called `view`. Put your authorization logic here.

Once you've built that, you can apply the policy in a variety of ways, like controller functions, middleware on your routes, or directly within views using the `@can` Blade directive.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization#authorizing-actions-using-policies

Answer (score 0):

This should work just fine for me, but rather than bombing the model class, I would extract it to the trait.

Answer (score 0):

You can make roles and permissions tables

**User** model:

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
}
```

**Role** model:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}

public function permissions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class);
}
```

**Permission** model:

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
}
```

then in app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider you can make Gate like this:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    foreach ($this->getPermissions() as $permission) {
        Gate::define($permission->name,function($user) use($permission){
            return $user->hasRole($permission->roles);
        });
    }


}
private function getPermissions(){
    return Permission::with('roles')->get();
}
```

at the end you can use ACL everywhere you want by just write Gate name like:show-comments or access-files or ....